# How can I return a document/node from a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, orientdb

If I do something like `select from #12:1`, obviously, it will return the full document:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#12:1",
            "@version": 1,
            "@class": "Package",
            "name": "MsPortfolioStack4.Repository-1.0.4549.25474-alpha",
            "p_name": "MsPortfolioStack4.Repository",
            "p_ver": "1.0.4549.25474-alpha",
            "tags": [
                "#14:1",
                "#14:2"
            ],
            "@fieldTypes": "tags=z"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.022 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

Now, if I have a JS function that does this:

```
function return_node(query) {
    return query;
}
```

And I execute `select return_node((select from #12:1))`, I only get the RID:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#-2:1",
            "@version": 0,
            "return_node": [
                "#12:1"
            ],
            "@fieldTypes": "return_node=z"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.058 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

Is it possible to return an actual expanded document rather than just the RID? At the moment, the fastest way seems to be to traverse the results, but that's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the JS function

var db=orient.getDatabase();
return db.query(query);

and execute
select expand(return_node("select from #12:1")) from (select return_node("select from #12:1"))

Comment: OK, `select expand(return_node) from (select return_node((select from #12:1)))` is slightly more efficient, but it is still performing two lookups (the initial query, and the document lookup). My question is whether it's possible to return an ODocument or an OResultSet from JavaScript without having to expand it again in SQL.